# UIWebview: Does not rotate and does not resize to fit the whole screen

Tags: ios, uiwebview, xcode4

The test code is available [here](https://github.com/reader20/Study) for your comments.

1) Rotation problem:

I have implemented

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}
```

in the WebViewController.m file, but it still does not rotate. (See the pictures below)

[image: Portrait]

[image: Landscape]

2) The size issue

As you may notice in the pictures, the bottom part of the screen is blank (about 25% of the screen). I have checked the xib file and the UIWebView seems to be set correctly

Did I make any very obvious mistake?

Comment: The test code is gone please fix this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not retaining the view controller for the web view in the application delegate.

To fix replace,

```
[self.window addSubview:wvc.view] -> [[self window] setRootViewController:wvc];
```